# How to find out range (min & max) value in sepal length column for each flower types

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science, iris-dataset

There are three types of flowers in the attached dataset(iris dataset) and I want to find out the range of sepal_length for all flower types. How can I do it?

**Dataset**

[image]

Dataset has 5 columns namely SEPAL_LENGHT,SEPAL_WIDTH,PETAL_LENGTH,PETAL_WIDTH & SPECIES.
In the SPECIES columns, three types of flowers are mentioned namely `['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`.

I want to find out the range of sepal_length and all other lengths(the rest of 3 columns) for all three species of flowers. Please tell me how can I do it.

I wrote below code for it but it doesn't work

```py
def rang(species,length):
    
    for i in (df.species.unique):
        
        if df.species=='setosa':
            
            mini=min(length)
            maxi=max(length)
            ran=max(length)-min(length)
            
            return(mini,maxi,ran)
        
        else:
            pass
```

when I run the above written code an error pops up :

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: try to use `groupby()` method of DataFrame.  For example like this: `df.groupby('SPECIES').max() - df.groupby('SPECIES').min()`

Comment: Thank you but can you also suggest how can I use a function to do it ?

Comment: @Pranav167 Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to min/max value in multiple columns of a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538497/how-to-min-max-value-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)